# update quantity with one button php

Tags: php

Hello i am currently doing a project to make a website that sells game however one of my problems right now is updating the quantity with a single button. i have got it working with multiple update buttons next to the items that i would like to update but to make it more realistic, i would like to just have one button that will update all the item quantities in the basket table in my database.

**This is my cart file, i have commented out the bit where it works with multiple update buttons.**

```
<?php
     $count = 0;
     while ($count < $numrow)
     {
     $row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
     extract($row);
     echo"<div>";
     echo"<div class='recommended_games'>";
     echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
     echo "</div>";


     echo '<div class="price_tag">';
     echo '<div class="price_tag">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
     echo'</div>';

     echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="POST" name="updateform" id="update_all">';
     echo '<select name="quantity" id="quantity" />';
     echo      '<option value="1">1</option>';
     echo      '<option value="2">2</option>';
     echo      '<option value="3">3</option>';
     echo      '<option value="4">4</option>';
     echo      '<option value="5">5</option>';
     echo      '</select>';
     //echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
     //echo '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';             
     echo '</form>';

     echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
     echo"</div>";
     $count = $count + 1;   

     }     
     echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" form="update_all"/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="update" form="update_all"/>';

 ?>
```

**This is my updatebasket file which updates the quantity in the database**

```
<?php
session_start();
require "dbconnect.php";

$memberID = $_SESSION['id']; 

$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$gameID = $_POST['gameid'];
$connect->query($query);


$query = "UPDATE basket SET quantity = ".$quantity." WHERE gameid = ".$gameID." AND id = ".$memberID."";

$results = $connect->query($query);


mysqli_commit($con);
header('Location: cart.php');
?>
```

Comment: You're missing single quotes in `$query = "UPDATE basket SET quantity = ".$quantity." WHERE gameid = ".$gameID." AND id = ".$memberID."";` see if adding them will help `$query = "UPDATE basket SET quantity = '".$quantity."' WHERE gameid = '".$gameID."' AND id = '".$memberID."'";` that could be one of the issues.

Comment: @Fred -ii- If the 3 values are INT's it should make no difference.

Comment: i did have the single quotes before but then i deleted them to see if they made a difference but noope :/. i tried taking it out of the loop and reference the form in my <input> tag but it only updates the last item quantity and not the whole basket.

Comment: as i ask you at top of comment. is it your $gameID and $memberID is int?

Comment: sorry, yes they are an int

Comment: in your database is it set the field in int?

Comment: yeah they are also int in the database

Comment: is it your $gameID is unique? because i saw that you only call 1 time in your form. what i mean is you only want to update the only $gameid?

Comment: the game id is unique yes but the its in a loop so it will call as many gameid as it needs everytime you put a game in the basket

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to work with an array for this to be achieved, by changing your form and you can use a foreach to assemble your query to update each entry in the cart. So one button will update each item in the cart with the respective quantities. I did not test this code, this is how I would approach it.

**Eample of the HTML Form Changes:**

```
echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="POST" name="updateform" id="update_all">';
     echo '<select name="quantity[]" id="quantity" />';
     echo      '<option value="1">1</option>';
     echo      '<option value="2">2</option>';
     echo      '<option value="3">3</option>';
     echo      '<option value="4">4</option>';
     echo      '<option value="5">5</option>';
     echo      '</select>';
     //echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid[]" id="gameid" />';
     //echo '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';             
     echo '</form>';
echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
     echo"</div>";
     $count = $count + 1;   

     }     
     echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid[]" id="gameid" form="update_all"/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="update" form="update_all"/>';

 ?>
```

**Query Eample:**

```
foreach ($_POST['gameid'] as $row=>$id) {
     $gameid = $id;
     $newquantity = ($_POST['quantity'][$row]);
         $query = "UPDATE basket SET quantity = ".$newquantity." WHERE gameid = ".$gameID." AND id = ".$memberID."";
     $connect->query($query);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however i just tried this and no success for me :(

Comment: try to change $newquantity = ($_POST['quantity'][$row]); to $newquantity = ($row[$id]);

Comment: @user3188359 That was more pseudo code to guide you in the right direction, but was I understanding your question?

Comment: yeah you understood it perfectly thank you i am still yet to to tinker with it since i had to re install xampp and everything

Comment: Excellent, take your time to get everything setup and working again.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to give your quantity `<select>` inputs unique names with the Game ID attached to the end (eg. "quantity_32"). This makes it easy to know how much of each game is in the cart.

```
// POST Example
$_POST['quantity_32'] = 1;
$_POST['quantity_31'] = 3;
$_POST['quantity_37'] = 2;
```

**Front-End Form Change**

```
echo '<select name="quantity_<?=$gameID?>" id="quantity" />';
```

**Back-End Processing**

Then on the processing page loop through the $_POST variables and find the quantity fields and grab their Game ID's.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $quantity) {
    // Ignore non-quantity fields
    if (preg_match('/quantity_([0-9]+)/i', $key, $result) !== 1) continue;
    $quantity = (int)$quantity;
    $game_id = (int)$result[1];

    // Update Cart Quantity in DB
    // ...
}
```

**Important!**

Please ensure you SQL-Escape all values you save into the DB. Hackers could do some nasty stuff if you don't.

This example shows how you can keep things safe using MySQLi Prepared Statements.
http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/